# Android OnConfigurationChanged not being called when I plug or unplug usb keyboard

Tags: android, keyboard, usb, soft-keyboard, onconfigurationchanged

this is my onConfigurationChanged :

```
 @Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) { //this will change the language, if needed.
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);

    Log.i("onConfigurationChanged", "keyboard: " + getResources().getConfiguration().keyboard);

    if (newConfig.hardKeyboardHidden == Configuration.HARDKEYBOARDHIDDEN_NO) {
        //A hardware keyboard is being connected
        Log.i("onConfigurationChanged", "HARDKEYBOARDHIDDEN_NO");

    } else if (newConfig.hardKeyboardHidden == Configuration.HARDKEYBOARDHIDDEN_YES) {
        //A hardware keyboard is being disconnected
        Log.i("onConfigurationChanged", "HARDKEYBOARDHIDDEN_YES");

    }

    Utils.setLocale(getBaseContext(), newConfig);
}
```

And this is my activity:

```
  <activity
        android:name="com.vidyo.vidyomod.activities.VMBaseActivity"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:launchMode="singleInstance"
        android:screenOrientation="landscape"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
    </activity>
```

Why isn't onConfigurationChanged called then? when I plug/unplug the keyboard?
Cause I've set the configChanges, I need to find a way to know when I have a usb keyboard plugged or not.

PS: getActivity().getResources().getConfiguration().hardKeyboardHidden returns 2 => HARDKEYBOARDHIDDEN_YES even if my usb keyboard is connected. why?

EDIT: Even if onConfigurationChanged is not called:
I get this logs:

```
07-12 07:40:41.749: D/EventHub(997): No input device configuration file found for device 'LITEON Technology USB Multimedia Keyboard'.
07-12 07:40:41.759: I/EventHub(997): New device: id=11, fd=195, path='/dev/input/event7', name='LITEON Technology USB Multimedia Keyboard', classes=0x80000403, configuration='', keyLayout='/system/usr/keylayout/Generic.kl', keyCharacterMap='/system/usr/keychars/Generic.kcm', builtinKeyboard=false, usingSuspendBlockIoctl=true, usingClockIoctl=true
07-12 07:40:41.759: I/InputReader(997): Device added: id=11, name='LITEON Technology USB Multimedia Keyboard', sources=0x00002103
```

Cant I take this from somewhere? like a event listener on the EventHub or something?

Comment: Opps! sorry the previous comment I was wrongly understand the question.

Comment: Try to remove keyboard|screenSize these property and then try it.

Comment: Most important write super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig); at the end of onConfigurationChanged() tag. Do all your stuff then call super method.

Comment: I removed keyboard|screenSize but nothing happens. Will try the second fix now

Comment: nope, that doesn't work neither, still not being called

Comment: Try to just print the log in onCreate() and trace out whether it is called or not. I have dought that it is being called because of android:launchMode="singleInstance".

Comment: whether what is being called? onConfigurationCalled? onCreate?

Comment: onCreate is called because of singleInstance property.

Comment: Yes, so onCreate is only called once at the beginning, is not created anymore when I add or remove the keyboard. (tried also with singleInstance removed)

Comment: Try this one may be this help you out. android:screenOrientation="sensor"

Comment: yes, now onConfigurationCalled is being called, atleast when I change screen layouts, will beed to see if it happens on keyboard added

Comment: finally it is called sir :)

Comment: but it still doesn't get called for removing/adding hardkeyboard :(
And the app being for a TV box set, it won't get called for the sensor neither, cause the tv is in landscape, and has no gyroscopes

Comment: The application is for android tv?

Comment: this in particular: http://minix.us/products/images/x9/NEO-X9.pdf

Comment: Try this one android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize|stateVisible"

Comment: Another try to comment or remove this super method and then try super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig); just comment this method.

Comment: tried both and nothing. It is not being called, neither for when the softkeyboard appears/disappears, or when I connect, disconnect hard keyboard

Answer (score 4):

I had a similar problem with a Samsung bluetooth keyboard for Samsung Tab S2.

My `onConfigurationChanged()` method did not fire until I put this line into the manifest.

```
android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize|navigation"
```

The only documentation I could find was [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#config).

The `navigation` keyword refers to the touchpad, which most physical devices have, and which most soft keyboards do not.

To quote the doco: *The navigation type (trackball/dpad) has changed. (This should never normally happen.)*

A fine example of poor android documentation being as costly as poor code!